# Keep subviews not transformed during UIScrollView zooming

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I have `UIScrollView` with content view that has a lot of different subviews (including some labels) on it. During zooming of content view all these different subviews are zoomed as anticipated. However I would like text of `UILabel` subviews not changed.
I tried next:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {
   // ...
   UILabel* label = (UILabel*)[scrollView viewWithTag:labelTag];
   [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1/scrollView.zoomScale, 1/scrollView.zoomScale)];  
}
```

Though the resulted text looks ugly (especially when scale factor quite big), even if I call `[label setContentScaleFactor:scaleFactor]` during `scrollViewDidEndZooming:`.
What are possibilities to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Put the uilabel outside the scroll view. 
That would solve your problem. Everything would zoom apart from the label.

Comment: Yes, this way is much easier than trying to apply the inverse zoom to text labels that are already in the scroll view.  What you should do instead, is track the points in the scroll-view coordinate space (which you must be doing already in order to lay them out), then use the...

- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view

...method to find out where labels should be correspondingly positioned e.g. in the coordinate space of the scroll-views parent. Then add them to this parent instead.